# AJAX json data does not print in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json

i have a JSON data in Javascript made form array using JSON.stringify

```
{
   "user":"Mark",
   "id":"80",
   "0":["age","=","twenty four","varchar"],
   "1":["prefix","=","Mr.","enum"]
}
```

i am sending this via AJAX to PHP file. When i echo the POST i get the values

```
echo (serialize($_POST['data']));

s:263:
"{
    "user":"Mark",
    "id":"80",
    "0":["age","=","twenty four","varchar"],
    "1":["prefix","=","Mr.","enum"]
 }";
```

How can i get the POSTed data in an Array or Object. i have tried to do

> var_dump(json_decode($_POST['data']));
>   AND
>   var_dump(json_decode(serialize($_POST['data']))); 
>   AND
>   var_dump(json_decode($_POST['data'],true));

but they did not work. Output is null.

Comment: Are you sure this is all your input? [Seem to be working fine](http://codepad.viper-7.com/PFeM7p) for me.

Comment: Printing $_POST['data'] gives me  >    {"user":"Mark","id":"80","0":["age","!=","twenty four","varchar"],"1":["prefix","=","Mr.","enum"]}

Comment: While var_dump(json_decode($_POST['data'])); gives me null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) should do the trick for you, but depending on your server config (if [magic_quotes_gpc](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) is on), you might need to use [stripslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) before decoding.

Answer (score 0):

If your PHP versopn >=5.2.0, you can use following build in PHP functions to decode JSONS

```
json_decode($_POST['data'])
```

It return Array and StdClass object.

Edit: How did you found json_decode is not working. Please try ver_dump or print_r. Hoping your PHP version >=5.2.0

Answer (score 0):

You have to store it to something.

```
$posted = json_decode($_POST['data']);
var_dump($posted);
```